# Need API call to fetch list of 11k clothing brand names in FlutterFlow

Tags: flutterflow

I am creating an app to track Cost per Wear of clothing items.

In the app, I ask the user to select the brand of the clothing item they want to input into their "closet" so that they can track the item's cost per wear.

I pulled a list of all the clothing brands on websites like Poshmark and Depop, and its about 11,000 brand names.

Obviously, in FlutterFlow I can't store that list, so I have that list in a google sheet (its 1 column with 11,000 rows) where each cell is a brand name.

My problem is that with the API call, the range that it's searching through is too big A1:A11141

This freezes my app. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to create my dropdown list with the 11k brands, in a way that won't freeze the whole app?

When a user clicks on the dropdown menu, it freezes the whole app. I want a user to be able to somehow select the brand of their clothing item from the list.

Also, in the dropdown I do have a search bar already, so they can start typing. This issue is just that the API Call is collecting such a large list of data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Why do you need to use a drop down component?

Comment: I don't necessarily need to, I guess. The goal of the dropdown is so that the user picks from a list of brand names, rather than typing it themselves. For example, if a user has 2 items from Abercrombie, I don't want them to manually type "Abercrombie" because for the second item they might accidentally type Abercrombie & Fitch, in which case the data will be messed up because the items won't be categorized as the same brand. That's why I want to user to choose brands only from a list.

But doesn't have to be a dropdown I guess.. I am trying to figure out a different way to show the brands